# Img srcset doesn't update on iPhone orientation change

Tags: html, image, responsive, responsive-images, srcset

When I display the `img` element with `srcset` attribute from the code below on my `iPhone 7` (375 x 667 @2x) on portrait mode it shows me image 1000 x 500, which is correct (tested on Safari and Chrome)

## Problem

The problem appears when I rotate my phone to horizontal mode. Then the size stays the same (1000 x 500) which is incorrect because on the horizontal mode site's width is equal to 667px and when you multiply it by 2 (pixel density) it's equal to 1334px, which is bigger than 1000px, so it should show the 1500 x 7500 image.

When you will reload the page and stay on the horizontal mode the correct image will appear (1500 x 750).

## Question

Why my phone doesn't update the image when I'm changing its orientation?
Is it by design or is it some kind of a bug?

## Code

```css
body { margin: 0 }
```

```html
<img
  src="https://placehold.co/2000x1000"
  srcset="
    https://placehold.co/500x250   500w,
    https://placehold.co/1000x500  1000w,
    https://placehold.co/1500x750  1500w,
    https://placehold.co/2000x1000 2000w,
    https://placehold.co/3000x1500 3000w" />
```

## Link with a demo from the code snippet

http://srcset.salcode.com/

Comment: This might help https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28682493/css-to-auto-fit-image-to-screen-when-iphone-rotated-from-portrait-to-landscape

Comment: The link above is not related to this problem. In my case browser doesn't update img to have the proper src (which is defined in srcset which is related to the browser's width)